# XPath expression of unknown XML leaf by matching keyword

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

Is it even possible?

XML:

```
<node name="unknown">
 <leaf ref="sometext/WHATIWANT/sometext"/>
</node>
<node name="unknown">
 <leaf ref="sometext/sometext/sometext"/>
</node>
<node name="unknown">
 <leaf ref="sometext/sometext/sometext"/>
</node>
```

`WHATIWANT` is what I know and want to match in my search.

I supposed to create a variable like `<xsl:variable name="whatiwant" select="contains(node(), '/WHATIWANT/')"/> <!-- unique -->` to use it in further expressions. 
Obviously it didn't work.
I suggest `select="contains(node(), '/WHATIWANT/')` does not check expression in xml leaf.

Any ideas how to check xml expression using known keyword?
Or select it different way?

Comment: It did not changed anything :(
Output - false

Comment: Are your XML elements *really* called `<leaf1>` through `<leaf-N>` or are they actually all called `<leaf>`?

Comment: @Tomalak, no its an example. They have different names. Not structured. Mb it is, but not for me.

Comment: Please make representative examples. If the elements are not called like that in real life, don't call them like that in your sample code. For your readers its completely impossible to know the difference, but it has an impact on how they approach the solution. Don't post made-up XML.

Comment: @Tomalak I'll pay attention to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Literally `leaf` elements

This XPath,

```
//leaf[contains(@ref, '/WHATIWANT/')]
```

will select all `leaf` elements whose `@ref` attribute value contains the substring `/WHATIWANT/`.

---

### Leaf elements only

This XPath,

```
//*[contains(@ref, '/WHATIWANT/') and not(*)]
```

will select all ***leaf*** elements whose `@ref` attribute value contains the substring `/WHATIWANT/`.

---

### All elements

This XPath,

```
//*[contains(@ref, '/WHATIWANT/')]
```

will select all elements, ***regardless of name and hierarchical position***, whose `@ref` attribute value contains the substring `/WHATIWANT/`.

Comment: Seems to be the correct answer. You must search in the ref attribute for your string.

Comment: Thank you! It works well, but I forgot to say. the `leaf` is always different in several XMLs.

Comment: If necessary, you could use `[not(*)]` to make sure it's a leaf node.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: Right, was adding concurrently with your comment!  Lol.  Thanks.

Comment: @kjhughes & michael.hor257k Many thanks! Now I know more.

Is there a way to output the XML expression?